# What is "well known" file associated with ``gcloud`` command line tool

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

In some [gcloud code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/blob/master/gcloud/credentials.py#L42) I'm finding a comment:

> Stored "well known" file associated with `gcloud` command line tool

What is this "well known" file?

Comment: Sounds related to : https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/144 where "well known" might mean "permissions too loose", but I'm not sure I'm reading it right. But that issue does do some of the legwork on where to look for where "well known" as a term originates.

Comment: No command returns the message. It's a comment in the code. I need to find that file.

Comment: Yeah, that just sank in and I deleted the comment. I still think "well known" is either code for "common/predefined location" or "file with weak permissions".

Comment: @Anthony yes it sounds like that sort of thing. If they weren't trying for security through obscurity there'd be no need for this question :-/

Comment: Yeah, It looks like "Well known" file refers to `WELL_KNOWN_CREDENTIALS_FILE` which gets defined by `_get_well_known_file()`. So it's not actually some special list of files that the client likes or has preference for (like they have a good rep, or are just "well known") it's just their way of saying "pre-established elsewhere".

Comment: I'm trying to get the phrase "security through reassurity" to catch on, which is basically security based on hyper complex policies that make either non-IT top brass feel safe or IT top brass feel like they've covered their ass. So not quite security through obscurity as much as "security through complexity" combined with "the illusion of strong security through proven weak practices". Pass it along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py#L1367

For Linux/MacOSX, it's
~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json